# Why should two equal objects return equal hash codes if I don't want to use my object as a key in a hash table?

Tags: java, overriding, equals, hashcode

This is what the Java documentation of [Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) says:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

But they don't explain *why* two equal objects must return equal hash codes. Why did Oracle engineers decided `hashCode` must be overriden when overriding `equals`?

The typical implementation of `equals` doesn't call the `hashCode` method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    if (this == arg0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(arg0 instanceof MyClass)) {
        return false;
    }
    MyClass another = (MyClass) arg0;
    // compare significant fields here
}
```

In *Effective Java (2nd Edition)* I read:

> **Item 9: Always override hashCode when you override equals.**
>
> A common source of bugs is the failure to override the hashCode
>   method. You must override hashCode in every class that overrides
>   equals. Failure to do so will result in a violation of the general
>   contract for Object.hashCode, which will prevent your class from
>   functioning properly in conjunction with all hash-based collections,
>   including HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable.

Suppose I don't need to use `MyClass` as a key of a hash table. Why do I need to override `hashCode()` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously if nobody ever calls your class's `hashCode` method, nobody will know that it's inconsistent with `equals`. Can you guarantee that for the duration of your project, including the years in maintenance, no one will need to, say, remove duplicate objects from a list or associate some extra bit of data with your objects?

You are probably just safer implementing `hashCode` so that it's consistent with equals. It's not particularly hard, always returning 0 is already a valid implementation.

<sub>(please don't just return 0 though)</sub>

Comment: I would not call "always returning 0" a "valid implementation".  I think the default implementation in `Object` is probably better

Comment: Returning a constant fulfills the contract. If you override `equals` the inherited `hashCode` implementation from `Object` does not.

Comment: Returning a constant does not fulfill the contract. The contract is not fulfilled by simply overiding `hashCode()`. the contract is fulfilled if `hashCode()` returns same value for instances that are equal and different values for instances that are not equal (according to `equals()`)

Comment: Different hashes for objects that are not equal is not required by the contract. In fact that's what makes hashes useful in the first place. Try to implement hash code for String -can you make it completely collision-free?

Comment: you are right. sorry about the confusion on my part.

Answer (score 4):

Of course when you have a little program only written by your self and you check every time you use an external lib that this did not rely on `hashCode()` then you can ignore all this warnings. But when a software projects grows you will use external libraries and and these will rely on `hashCode()`and you will lose a lot of time searching for bugs. Or in a newer Java version some other classes use the `hashCode()`too and your program will fail.

So its a lot easier to just implement this and follow this easy rule, because an modern IDE can auto generate `equals` and `hashCode` with one click.

**Update a little story**: At work we ignored this rule too in a lot of classes and only implemented the one needed mostly `equals` or `compareTo`. Some day some strange things happen, because one programmer has used a Hash*-Class in the GUI and our Objects did not follow this rule. In the end an apprentice need to search all classes with `equals` and have to add the corresponding `hashCode` method.

Answer (score 3):

As the text says, it's a violation of the general contract that is in use. Of course if you never ever use it in any place that hashCode would be required nobody is forcing you to implement it.

But what if some day in the future it is needed? What if the class is used by some other developer? That's why there is this contract that both of them have to be implemented, so there is no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `hashCode` has to be overridden to agree with `equals` is because of why and how `hashCode` is used. Hash codes are used as surrogates for values so that when mapping a key value to something hashing can be used to give near-constant lookup time with reasonable space. When two values compare equal (ie, they are the same value) then they have to map to the same something when used as a key for a hashed collection. That requires that they have the same hash code to get them there.

You have to override `hashCode` appropriately because the manual says you have to. It says you have to because the decision was made that libraries can assume that you are satisfying that contract so they (& you) can have the performance benefits of hashing when using a value that you gave it as a key in their functions' implementations.

Answer (score -2):

The common wizdom dictates that the logic for `// compare significant fields here` is required for `equals()` and also for `compareTo()` (in case you want to sort instances of `MyClass`) and also for using hash tables. so it makes sense to put this logic in `hashCode()` and have the other methods use the hash code.